# leaflet layer interrupting interactivity of base layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

I am working on a project based on the [Leaflet Choropleth Tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/).

In my map, I have three base layers that the user switches between

```
var basemaps= {
"layer1": layer1,
"layer2": layer 2,
"layer3": layer 3
};
```

Each of these layers highlights and displays popup information just like in the Choropleth template.

I also have layers that display labels(values) for each region, depending which one is active.

```
var activelabel = L.layerGroup();
var showlabels = {
  "labels": activelabel
};

map.on('baselayerchange', function (event) {
  activelabel.clearLayers();

  switch (event.layer) {
    case layer1:
      label1.addTo(activelabel);
      break;
    case layer2:
      label2.addTo(activelabel);
      break;
    case layer3:
      label3.addTo(activelabel);
      break;
  }
});
```

My problem, is that when the labels are active, if the user hovers over the part of the region where the label is, the highlight feature and info box do not display any information.

I am trying to find a way to make the activelabel layer invisible, so that the hover still works.

I found the tutorial on [Map Panes](http://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/), which seems like the solution to my problem, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

I'm not sure if i'm putting the pane information in the wrong spot, or if this doesn't actually work like I think it should? I've tried changing the xIndex everywhere from 0 to 700 and it doesn't seem to make a difference?

```
map.createPane('labels');
map.getPane('labels').style.zIndex = 700;
map.getPane('labels').style.pointerevents = 'none';
```

I've tried putting the pane: 'labels' code here, where I format my labels

```
var createLabelIcon = function(labelClass,labelText){
return L.divIcon({ 
className: labelClass,
html: labelText
})
};
```

as well as here, where I create the layer group.

```
var label1 = new L.layerGroup();                        
makelabel1();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution to this. I have three separate .js files where I add all the layers containing labels to my layergroups.

If I add {interactive: false} to each instance of .addLayer in each file, the labels to not interrupt the mouse hover.

I'm not sure why this doesnt work when I add interactive:false to the layer group as opposed to each addLayer line, but it seems to be working.

Comment: Leaflet only looks at the options of each layer specifically as it adds them and not the overall group.  The interactive option is specific to certain Leaflet object types (path, circle, rectangle, etc).  It's a reasonable assumption though and would make for a great idea to pose in their github account, having a group level option that propagates to all layers involved.